Using full site editing, unable to select a new tempate for page in editor
Maybe I'm not understanding how this works. I'm trying to change the template used for my Home page. Here's my setup:
Note: This is similar, but still different, to a question I asked a couple years ago.

Created a Home Page (shows with "Front Page" suffix in listing) in Pages and made it the static Homepage in Settings > Reading
In Appearance > Editor > Patterns, I made a header and footer
Then, in Appearance > Editor > Templates I made a Front Page template using the New Template option and selecting Front Page from the pop-up
– There is also a template called Index, but it is empty
– The Home page appears on the client side with everything as set

So, what's the problem?
Well, when I edit the Home Page under All Pages, Template in the right side bar show Index. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ and I can't change it.
Questions: 1) Why does the blank Index appear by default in the page editor? 2) Why can't I change it? 3) And why does the Home page appear correctly despite all this?
